# How do I include the Chromedriver into my Python 3.6 path so that my selenium would work?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

`enter code here`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HNF0.jpg)

I get syntax error, I am trying to locate the chromedriver in my Jupyter folder but it's not showing or not working. I have BeautifulSoup imported... 
What could I be missing?

Answer (score 2):

There is a space between `Chrome` and `(path)`. Just remove it as

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
```

Also you need to pass `path` to file as `string`, like `"C:\\Users\\...\\chromedriver"`. Note the quotes (you can use both single `' '` or double quotes `" "`)

Comment: Thank you for the input but I still get this - NameError: name 'webdriver' is not defined. I tried 64x and 32x versions of the chromedriver. I added into the folder where the driver is located and Python but they still can't get to the path...

Comment: This might mean that you have your own script that called `selenium.py`... try `import selenium` and then `selenium.__file__` from `Python` shell to get path to file you actually import. If it doesn't located in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` then rename it